# Handling gaming keyboard with extra keys to be able to bind shortcuts

Tags: key-bindings

I bought keyboard `SteelSeries Apex 350` thinking that I can somehow bind  extra keys with vim. I am looking for answers in the Internet regarding this subject but I am not lucky so far. Have anyone tried to use gaming extra keys in vim?

Comment: I didn't get around to drafting a proper answer to this, but I think the solution is to use SSE3 engine (which is available from the manufacturer's website https://steelseries.com/downloads) to map the keys, either to something that you can then handle in Vim, or to macros that actually type out Vim commands. Here's a video showing how to do so https://youtu.be/yZGHa5bf3WU. It's for a different keyboard but according to steelseries.com it uses the same configuration software.

Comment: It does not solves the issue. The @laktak helped helped me to figure out what is happening (please refer to his comment).

Comment: Huh. From what I've read, you should be able to remap the keys to perform arbitrary sequences of keystrokes. Just out of interest, how does it fail?  Does the SSE3 engine not work as advertised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most terminals only support a limited set of key codes you need to solve your issue in two steps:

- Use Karabiner/Elements (Mac), Autohotkey (Windows), xkb/Autokey (Linux) or something similar to map the key to a combination that is supported in your terminal (like <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- Map that key (e.g. <kbd>F1</kbd>) in Vim

Karabiner/Autohotkey let you set the mapping only for the terminal, not sure how to do that with Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a very useful software, however the Event Viewer do not shows the special keys.

Comment: @ArturGurgul What's your OS? If you are using Linux take a look at this: https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl on a Mac the old Karabiner had support for this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osx-karabiner/5x9D5h5_KqE), for K. Elements I'm not sure. Doesn't the Apex include drivers to remap the keys as well?

Comment: My OS is macOS and the driver provided by Apex is very limited.

A vary nice finding, I will definitely try it out.

Comment: On macOS there are a few others if Karabiner does not work out: http://alternativeto.net/software/keyremap4macbook/?platform=mac

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're talking about the special keys on the left-hand side? 
[image]
Vim only sees ASCII text as input. This means that when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, Vim only sees `S` not the two individual keys. This is why you can't use a naked <kbd>Shift</kbd> as a binding. That being said, if your new keys produce some kind of ASCII output you should be able to use them as bindings by doing the following:

`noremap`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>{your key} {your binding}

Place the resulting line in your `vimrc`.

If on the other hand doing this doesn't produce ASCII output, I don't think there is any way for Vim to access them.

See [`:help i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V) for more info on how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> works.

Comment: "Vim only sees ASCII text as input" <- this isn't correct, and could do with rephrasing. You can type non-ASCII text into Vim, and you can also use non-ASCII in the {lhs} of a mapping: e.g. `:nnoremap é x` works fine.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was thinking that é was under the ASCII  standard but it's not. What's a better way to say that (because Vim doesn't take all Unicode characters IIRC)?